# Can I make my own lock screen?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Now my lock screen makes me enter a password.
But what if I want to make a custom lock screen like username and password.
Is it possible?

Comment: I am tempted to write an answer containing just one word: _Yes_. Because if you're willing to do the programming yourself, almost anything is "possible".

Comment: use xscreensaver https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-autostart-xscreensaver-ubuntu-16-04-16-10

Comment: Is it possible? Yes, I've done it several times in the past for my own Linux desktop environments. Is it easy? No, not at all. You need to have a very good understand of Linux system administration and programming before you could even attempt it